# Multi domain images not showing up

Tags: i18n-l10n, multi-sites, .htaccess

I have a multilingual site that has a different domain for each language (.eu, .com, .nl and. de). everything was functioning well untill today. The site shows an acces denied message when I try to reach an image on www.example.com/sites/default/files/styles/sliderfront/public/exampleimg.jpg?itok=i2WjbtxU and the images show up as broken image icons. however this doesn't happen whenever I reach the same file through www.example.eu/sites/...

Another thing is that this only happens with newly added content. All the files and maps within and including files/styles have permissions 755

The site is hosted on a shared hosting and its main domain is the  .eu domain.
Does it have something to do with symlinks?

Comment: I fixed the issue.. it turned out that I had a faulty module. Switched the monster off and the site worked as it should again.